# How do you list the primary key of a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simple question, how do you list the primary key of a table with T-SQL? I know how to get indexes on a table, but can't remember how to get the PK.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Tab.Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = '<your table name>'
```

Comment: FYI- this does not necessarily list the columns *in order*. See this answer to similar question if you need the columns in their particular order: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3942921/18511

Comment: Actually, I believe you have to also constrain by Schema, right? So, you'd need to add "And COL.TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your schema name>'" as well.

Comment: If the above query returns 3 rows, `a`, `b` and `c`, (in that order) then my table has a primary composite key of `abc`?

Answer (score 43):

It's generally recommended practice now to use the `sys.*` views over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in SQL Server, so unless you're planning on migrating databases I would use those. Here's how you would do it with the `sys.*` views:

```
SELECT 
    c.name AS column_name,
    i.name AS index_name,
    c.is_identity
FROM sys.indexes i
    inner join sys.index_columns ic  ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    inner join sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
    and i.object_ID = OBJECT_ID('<schema>.<tablename>');
```

Comment: To order, add 'ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal ASC' to the query

Answer (score 29):

This is a solution which uses only **sys**-tables.

It lists all the primary keys in the database. It returns **schema, table name, column name** and the correct **column sort order** for each primary key.

If you want to get the primary key for a specific table, then you need to filter on **`SchemaName`** and **`TableName`**.

IMHO, this solution is very generic and does not use any string literals, so it will run on any machine.

```
select 
    s.name as SchemaName,
    t.name as TableName,
    tc.name as ColumnName,
    ic.key_ordinal as KeyOrderNr
from 
    sys.schemas s 
    inner join sys.tables t   on s.schema_id=t.schema_id
    inner join sys.indexes i  on t.object_id=i.object_id
    inner join sys.index_columns ic on i.object_id=ic.object_id 
                                   and i.index_id=ic.index_id
    inner join sys.columns tc on ic.object_id=tc.object_id 
                             and ic.column_id=tc.column_id
where i.is_primary_key=1 
order by t.name, ic.key_ordinal ;
```

Answer (score 11):

Is using MS SQL Server you can do the following:

```sql
-- List all tables primary keys
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

You can also filter on the table_name column if you want a specific table.

Comment: this only lists the key, it does not list the columns in the key

Comment: This is off to the right start, but needs to be joined with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE as in the answer by Guy Starbuck.

Answer (score 11):

I like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA technique, but another I've used is:

```sql
exec sp_pkeys 'table'
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way from the question [get table primary key using sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3930338/1366033):

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA+'.'+CONSTRAINT_NAME), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
  AND TABLE_NAME = '<your table name>'
```

It uses [`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189789.aspx) to determine the constraints for a given table
Then uses [`OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsPrimaryKey')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) to determine if each is a primary key

Answer (score 5):

I am telling a simple Technic which I follow

```
SP_HELP 'table_name'
```

run this code as query. Mention your table name at place of table_name for which you want to know Primary Key (don't forget the single quotes). The result will show like attached Image. Hope it will help you

[image]

Comment: Make sure you surround your table name in single quotes or the command will not work!

Answer (score 4):

--This is another Modified Version which is also an example for Co-Related Query

```
SELECT TC.TABLE_NAME as [Table_name], TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME as [Primary_Key]
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU
 ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 WHERE TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
 TC.TABLE_NAME IN
 (SELECT [NAME] AS [TABLE_NAME] FROM SYS.OBJECTS 
 WHERE TYPE = 'U')
```

Answer (score 3):

**This should list all the constraints ( primary Key and Foreign Keys ) and at the end of query   put table name**

```
/* CAST IS DONE , SO THAT OUTPUT INTEXT FILE REMAINS WITH SCREEN LIMIT*/
WITH   ALL_KEYS_IN_TABLE (CONSTRAINT_NAME,CONSTRAINT_TYPE,PARENT_TABLE_NAME,PARENT_COL_NAME,PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE,REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCE_COL_NAME) 
AS
(
SELECT  CONSTRAINT_NAME= CAST (PKnUKEY.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE=CAST (PKnUKEY.type_desc AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_TABLE_NAME=CAST (PKnUTable.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME=CAST ( PKnUKEYCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE=  oParentColDtl.DATA_TYPE,        
        REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME='' ,
        REFERENCE_COL_NAME='' 

FROM sys.key_constraints as PKnUKEY
    INNER JOIN sys.tables as PKnUTable
            ON PKnUTable.object_id = PKnUKEY.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns as PKnUColIdx
            ON PKnUColIdx.object_id = PKnUTable.object_id
            AND PKnUColIdx.index_id = PKnUKEY.unique_index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns as PKnUKEYCol
            ON PKnUKEYCol.object_id = PKnUTable.object_id
            AND PKnUKEYCol.column_id = PKnUColIdx.column_id
     INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oParentColDtl
            ON oParentColDtl.TABLE_NAME=PKnUTable.name
            AND oParentColDtl.COLUMN_NAME=PKnUKEYCol.name
UNION ALL
SELECT  CONSTRAINT_NAME= CAST (oConstraint.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FK',
        PARENT_TABLE_NAME=CAST (oParent.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME=CAST ( oParentCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        PARENT_COL_NAME_DATA_TYPE= oParentColDtl.DATA_TYPE,     
        REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME=CAST ( oReference.name AS VARCHAR(30)) ,
        REFERENCE_COL_NAME=CAST (oReferenceCol.name AS VARCHAR(30)) 
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oConstraint
            ON FKC.constraint_object_id=oConstraint.id 
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oParent
            ON FKC.parent_object_id=oParent.id
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns oParentCol
            ON FKC.parent_object_id=oParentCol.object_id /* ID of the object to which this column belongs.*/
            AND FKC.parent_column_id=oParentCol.column_id/* ID of the column. Is unique within the object.Column IDs might not be sequential.*/
    INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects oReference
            ON FKC.referenced_object_id=oReference.id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS oParentColDtl
            ON oParentColDtl.TABLE_NAME=oParent.name
            AND oParentColDtl.COLUMN_NAME=oParentCol.name
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns oReferenceCol
            ON FKC.referenced_object_id=oReferenceCol.object_id /* ID of the object to which this column belongs.*/
            AND FKC.referenced_column_id=oReferenceCol.column_id/* ID of the column. Is unique within the object.Column IDs might not be sequential.*/

)

select * from   ALL_KEYS_IN_TABLE
where   
    PARENT_TABLE_NAME  in ('YOUR_TABLE_NAME') 
    or REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME  in ('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
ORDER BY PARENT_TABLE_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

For reference please read thru - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/09/16/469136.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The system stored procedure `sp_help` will give you the information. Execute the following statement:

```
execute sp_help table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.name AS 'table', i.name AS 'index', it.xtype,

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 1 
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column1',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 2 
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column2',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 3
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column3',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 4
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column4',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 5
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column5',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 6
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column6',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 7
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column7',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 8 
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column8',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 9 
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column9',

(SELECT c.name FROM syscolumns c INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k 
    ON k.indid = i.indid 
        AND c.colid = k.colid 
        AND c.id = t.id 
        AND k.keyno = 10
        AND k.id = t.id)
    AS 'column10',

FROM sysobjects t
    INNER JOIN sysindexes i ON i.id = t.id 
    INNER JOIN sysobjects it ON it.parent_obj = t.id AND it.name = i.name

WHERE it.xtype = 'PK'
ORDER BY t.name, i.name
```

Comment: For some reason I get an error on the sub queries returning multiple values. I tried commenting out each of the subqueries to see if I could pin point it, but they all seem to fail on the same table, which has only one field in it's index. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: I found that the problem was when a table function was listed. Not sure why, but the field counts for a column (i.e. column1) was 2. My fix was to change the final WHERE clause to "WHERE it.xtype='PK' AND t.[type] = 'U'".

Comment: I also prettied it up using the isnull function on each column select to avoid seeing 'NULL' in my result set. For example:
,ISNULL(
         (SELECT
                c.name
            FROM
                syscolumns c
            INNER JOIN sysindexkeys k ON k.indid = i.indid
                                         AND c.colid = k.colid
                                         AND c.id = t.id
                                         AND k.keyno = 1
                                         AND k.id = t.id), ''
        ) AS 'column1'

Answer (score 2):

This one gives you the columns that are PK.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 2):

For a comma separated list of primary key columns for a given TableName and Schema:

```
Select distinct SUBSTRING ( stuff(( select distinct ',' + [COLUMN_NAME] 
                                    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE  
                                    where OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1  
                                    AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Schema'  
                                    order by 1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'' ) 
                            ,2,9999)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guy.

With a slight variation I used it to find all the primary keys for all the tables.

```
SELECT A.Name,Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col ,
    (select NAME from dbo.sysobjects where xtype='u') AS A
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY '
    AND Col.Table_Name = A.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME as [Table_name], A.CONSTRAINT_NAME as [Primary_Key]
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS A, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE B
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = B.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will list **primary keys** of **particular table**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONSTRAINT_NAME AS [Constraint],
    TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Schema],
    TABLE_NAME AS TableName
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'mytablename'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do your own ORM or generate code from a given table, then this might be what you are looking form:

```
declare @table varchar(100) = 'mytable';

with cte as
(
    select 
        tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
        , tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
        , tc.TABLE_NAME
        , ccu.COLUMN_NAME
        , IS_NULLABLE
        , DATA_TYPE
        , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        , NUMERIC_PRECISION
    from 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
        inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu on tc.TABLE_NAME=ccu.TABLE_NAME  and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=ccu.TABLE_SCHEMA
        inner join information_schema.COLUMNS c on ccu.COLUMN_NAME=c.COLUMN_NAME and ccu.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME and ccu.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    where 
        tc.table_name=@table
        and 
        ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    union 
    select TABLE_SCHEMA,'COLUMN', TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE, DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@table
    and COLUMN_NAME not in (select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = @table)
)
select 
    cast(iif(CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY',1,0) as bit) PrimaryKey
    ,cast(iif(CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY',1,0) as bit) ForeignKey
    ,cast(iif(CONSTRAINT_TYPE='COLUMN',1,0) as bit) NotKey
    ,COLUMN_NAME
    ,cast(iif(is_nullable='NO',0,1) as bit) IsNullable
    , DATA_TYPE
    , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    , NUMERIC_PRECISION 
from 
    cte 
order by 
    case CONSTRAINT_TYPE 
        when 'PRIMARY KEY' then 1 
        when 'FOREIGN KEY' then 2 
        else 3 end
    , COLUMN_NAME
```

Here is what the result would look like:

```html
    <table cellspacing=0 border=1>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>PrimaryKey</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>ForeignKey</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NotKey</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>COLUMN_NAME</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>IsNullable</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>DATA_TYPE</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NUMERIC_PRECISION</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>LectureNoteID</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>int</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NULL</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>10</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>LectureId</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>int</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NULL</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>10</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NoteTypeID</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>int</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NULL</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>10</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>Body</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>nvarchar</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>-1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NULL</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>1</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>DisplayOrder</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>0</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>int</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>NULL</td>
      <td style=min-width:50px>10</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If Primary Key and type needed, this query may be useful:

```
SELECT L.TABLE_SCHEMA, L.TABLE_NAME, L.COLUMN_NAME, R.TypeName
FROM(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
)L
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName ,c.name AS ColumnName ,t.name AS TypeName
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
)R ON L.COLUMN_NAME = R.ColumnName AND L.TABLE_NAME = R.TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT
    CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AS DataBaseName,
    CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AS SchemaName,
    TABLE_NAME AS TableName,
    CONSTRAINT_Name AS PrimaryKey
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' and Table_Name = 'YourTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful, gives a list of tables with a comma separate list of the columns and then also a comma separate list of which ones are the primary key

```
SELECT T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME, 
STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS Columns,
STUFF((
SELECT ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
    ON C.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND C.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
    AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    FOR XML PATH ('')
), 1, 2, '') AS [Key]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
ORDER BY T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Something like this (?) :   Select distinct SUBSTRING ( stuff(( select distinct ',' + [COLUMN_NAME] 
                                    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE  
         where OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1  
         AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Schema'  
         order by 1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,0,'' ) 
       ,2,9999)

Answer (score 0):

This version displays the schema, the table name and an ordered, comma separated list of primary keys. Object_Id() does not work for link servers so we filter by the table name.

Without the REPLACE(Si1.Column_Name, '', '') it would show the xml opening and closing tags for Column_Name on the database I was testing on. I am not sure why the database required a replace for 'Column_Name' so if someone knows then please comment.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = '';
WITH Sysinfo
    AS (SELECT Kcu.Table_Name
            , Kcu.Table_Schema AS Schema_Name
            , Kcu.Column_Name
            , Kcu.Ordinal_Position
        FROM   [LinkServer].Information_Schema.Key_Column_Usage Kcu
             JOIN [LinkServer].Information_Schema.Table_Constraints AS Tc ON Tc.Constraint_Name = Kcu.Constraint_Name
        WHERE  Tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key')
    SELECT           Schema_Name
                    ,Table_Name
                    , STUFF(
                          (
                             SELECT ', '
                                 , REPLACE(Si1.Column_Name, '', '')
                             FROM    Sysinfo Si1
                             WHERE  Si1.Table_Name = Si2.Table_Name
                             ORDER BY Si1.Table_Name
                                   , Si1.Ordinal_Position
                             FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 2, '') AS Primary_Keys
    FROM Sysinfo Si2
    WHERE Table_Name = CASE
                       WHEN @TableName NOT IN( '', 'All')
                       THEN @TableName
                       ELSE Table_Name
                    END
    GROUP BY Si2.Table_Name, Si2.Schema_Name;
```

And the same pattern using George's query:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = '';
WITH Sysinfo
    AS (SELECT S.Name AS Schema_Name
            , T.Name AS Table_Name
            , Tc.Name AS Column_Name
            , Ic.Key_Ordinal AS Ordinal_Position
        FROM   [LinkServer].Sys.Schemas S
             JOIN [LinkServer].Sys.Tables T ON S.Schema_Id = T.Schema_Id
             JOIN [LinkServer].Sys.Indexes I ON T.Object_Id = I.Object_Id
             JOIN [LinkServer].Sys.Index_Columns Ic ON I.Object_Id = Ic.Object_Id
                                                       AND I.Index_Id = Ic.Index_Id
             JOIN [LinkServer].Sys.Columns Tc ON Ic.Object_Id = Tc.Object_Id
                                                  AND Ic.Column_Id = Tc.Column_Id
        WHERE  I.Is_Primary_Key = 1)
    SELECT           Schema_Name
                    ,Table_Name
                    , STUFF(
                          (
                             SELECT ', '
                                 , REPLACE(Si1.Column_Name, '', '')
                             FROM    Sysinfo Si1
                             WHERE  Si1.Table_Name = Si2.Table_Name
                             ORDER BY Si1.Table_Name
                                   , Si1.Ordinal_Position
                             FOR XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 2, '') AS Primary_Keys
    FROM Sysinfo Si2
    WHERE Table_Name = CASE
                       WHEN @TableName NOT IN('', 'All')
                       THEN @TableName
                       ELSE Table_Name
                    END
    GROUP BY Si2.Table_Name, Si2.Schema_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sys.Objects Table contains row for each user-defined, schema-scoped
>   object .
>
> Constraints created like Primary Key or others will be the *object* and
>   Table name will be the *parent_object*
>
> Query sys.Objects and collect the Object's Ids of Required Type

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(50)='TblInvoice' -- your table name
declare @TypeOfKey nvarchar(50)='PK' -- For Primary key

SELECT Name FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = @TypeOfKey 
AND  parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID (@TableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a more accurate simple answer to the original question below

```
SELECT 
KEYS.table_schema, KEYS.table_name, KEYS.column_name, KEYS.ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keys
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CONS 
    ON cons.TABLE_SCHEMA = keys.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND cons.TABLE_NAME = keys.TABLE_NAME 
    AND cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME = keys.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Notes:

1. Some of the answers above are missing a filter for just primary key
   columns!
2. I'm using below in a CTE to join to a larger column
   listing to provide the metadata from a source to feed BIML generation of staging tables and SSIS code

Answer (score 0):

Might be lately posted but hopefully this will help someone to see primary key list in sql server by using this t-sql query:

```
SELECT  schema_name(t.schema_id) AS [schema_name], t.name AS TableName,        
    COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS PrimaryKeyColumnName,
    i.name AS PrimaryKeyConstraintName
FROM    sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i  on t.object_id=i.object_id 
INNER JOIN  sys.index_columns AS ic ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
                            AND i.index_id = ic.index_id 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) = 'YourTableNameHere'
```

You can see the list of all foreign keys by using this query if you may want:

```
SELECT
f.name as ForeignKeyConstraintName
,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS ReferencingTableName
,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ReferencingColumnName
,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName
,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS 
 ReferencedColumnName  ,delete_referential_action_desc AS 
DeleteReferentialActionDesc ,update_referential_action_desc AS 
UpdateReferentialActionDesc
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc
ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
 --WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) = 'YourTableNameHere' 
 --If you want to know referecing table details 
 WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableNameHere' 
 --If you want to know refereced table details 
ORDER BY f.name
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found this from my friend, very effective if you are looking for all the table's primary keys under particular schema.**

```
SELECT tc.constraint_name AS IndexName,tc.table_name AS TableName,tc.table_schema
AS SchemaName,kc.column_name AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc,information_schema.key_column_usage kc
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND kc.table_name = tc.table_name AND kc.table_schema = tc.table_schema
AND kc.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name AND tc.table_schema='<SCHEMA_NAME>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution :)

`EXEC sp_pkeys YourTable`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at it for listing keys' data types as well based on any key constraints for primary or foreign keys.

```
SELECT 
    ksu.table_name as TableName, 
    ksu.column_name as ColumnName, 
    tc.constraint_type as ConstraintType, 
    c.Data_Type as DataType, 
    ksu.ordinal_position as OrdinalPosition
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ksu
    ON tc.Table_Name = ksu.Table_Name 
    and tc.Constraint_Name = ksu.Constraint_Name
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    ON c.Table_Name = ksu.Table_Name 
    and c.Column_Name = ksu.Column_Name
WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key' 
    --or tc.Constraint_Type = 'Foreign Key'
GROUP BY 
    ksu.table_name, ksu.column_name, tc.constraint_type, c.Data_Type, ksu.ordinal_position
ORDER BY ksu.table_name, ksu.column_name, tc.constraint_type, c.Data_Type
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you need it in Oracle it is so simple.

```
SELECT `Constraint_Name`
  FROM `All_Constraints`
 WHERE `Constraint_Type` = `'P'`
   AND `Owner` = `'your schema here';`
```