# Get a List of all Primary Keys in a Database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, primary-key

Is this the best way to - Get a List of all Primary Keys in a Database - or is there something better?

```
SELECT
KCU.TABLE_NAME AS Table_Name,
KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS Constraint_Name,
KCU.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU
ON KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND KCU.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
ORDER BY
KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA, KCU.TABLE_NAME, KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Comment: Please choose a better title. Also what do you mean by "best"?

Comment: You could probably also use @@Identity but i dunno if that's anywhere near what you mean?

Comment: The information schema is the best way indeed.

Comment: @cularis - RE: Your proposed tag edit `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` does definitely not imply `MySQL`. These are meant to be portable views.

Comment: Cheeky, posting the same question with different user name

Comment: Duplicate post : check this out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look on [link](http://databases.aspfaq.com/schema-tutorials/schema-how-do-i-show-all-the-primary-keys-in-a-database.html)

```
EXEC sp_pkeys '<tablename>'
EXEC sp_helpconstraint '<tablename>'
```

> sp_pkeys will return a row for each
>   column that participates in the
>   primary key for . The
>   columns you are likely most interested
>   in are COLUMN_NAME and PK_NAME.
>
> sp_helpconstraint will list all
>   constraints for , including
>   foreign keys that reference the table.
>   In the first recordset, there will
>   only be a column called Object Name
>   (kind of useless, since that's what
>   you passed in). In the second
>   resultset, there will be the following
>   columns: constraint_type,
>   constraint_name, and constraint_keys.

Comment: why is this the answer, it only does it for a table not a database, which was the original point of the question

Comment: The link referenced here is invalid

Comment: However you can get all tables used in the database and loop over those tables to get all primary keys

Answer (score 46):

```
USE databasename; 

GO

SELECT i.name AS IndexName, OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
       COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
```

This query will extract the all primary key constraints from the database...
 u just need to execute this query and type the database name in first line

Comment: Thank you for this. I have a LOT of tables and needed the keys for all tables to use in a new table, and this was the code I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The following syntax give you all constraints in database in use.

```
select * from sys.key_constraints;
```

Comment: To add to a response from @Ashraf, you can use `select OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), * from sys.key_constraints where type = 'PK'`. This will give you the table name and their primary key names for the tables that have a primary key.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the data type information as well:

```
SELECT 
    so.name 'Table Name',
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sysobjects so ON c.object_id = so.id
WHERE
    i.is_primary_key = 1 and 
    so.xtype = 'U'
Order By 'Table Name', 'Column Name'
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I spent an hour trying to find an answer which would allow me to find all of the PKs which are NOT int

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from java you can also use the getPrimaryKeys method in the databasemetadata object.  Perhaps other languages have similar ways to do it.