# Query to get all primary keys in a database

Tags: sql

Is this the best way to - Get a List of all Primary Keys in a Database - or is there something better?

```
SELECT
KCU.TABLE_NAME AS Table_Name,
KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS Constraint_Name,
KCU.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU
ON KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND KCU.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
ORDER BY
KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA, KCU.TABLE_NAME, KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a List of all Primary Keys in a Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108697/get-a-list-of-all-primary-keys-in-a-database)