# Searching for a PK or FK within all database tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to locate all instances of a specific key in my SQL tables. The value is numeric.

I am getting this error when using the script below:

> Error converting datatype numeric to varchar

Script

```
DECLARE @SearchStr varchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = '6836755'

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = @SearchStr--QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName =
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
          AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
          AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
              AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
              AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
              AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName)

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END   
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```

This works great for text values. I either need a way to modify this so it searches numbers, or if it is easier, a way to identify every table where a given FK is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play around with:

```
SELECT KU.table_name as TABLENAME,column_name as PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
          ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
             TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
ORDER BY KU.TABLE_NAME, KU.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Slightly modified from: [SQL Server: Get table primary key using sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query)