# pymssql INSERT won't auto increment ID

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, pymssql

I am using pymssql in my django project to connect to a database. 
I'm trying to use execute() method to do an insert.
However I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table ITEMS

the ID column is primary key and so it should be filled by the sql itself as I understand.
here is my insert command:

```
    bill_id = execute("""
       INSERT INTO ITEMS(COlUMN1,COlUMN2, COlUMN3,COlUMN4,COlUMN5)
       VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d, %d);
        """, (1713, 6, 929, 1184, 25))
```

and none of these COLUMNs are ID.
can anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use Django models to interact with the database?

Comment: @mhawke I can't do that. I'm working on a rather big project and it's not my call.

Comment: If the table was not created by Django, then the ID field may not have `AUTO_INCREMENT` set. You'll need to either specify the id, or alter the column so that it auto increments.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks. that might be the case. how would I alter the column?

Comment: You'll need to run the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` statement. I can't help with the exact syntax for MySQL.

Comment: @Alasdair ok thanks. I'll figure out the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If id column is not an auto increment key column, it will not work. If you define a column in SQL within a create table statement it is not automatically an autoincrement column. You must define it. Perhaps you should make at first a query to get the max value of id column. At second you can increment the value und add the primary column to your insert statement.

I found this link to use django meta data api.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api

Comment: thanks, that's what I did eventually, but I still can't figure out why the id is not being set by sql. the column is auto increment so it should increment by itself.

Comment: Ok, it is an MySQL Database.

Comment: Try the following to show the structure of table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Comment: Ok, you use MS-SQL Server. The following shows you an possibility to show meta Data of table. At first analyse the structure. If you are 100% sure that it is an autoincrement column. I can not say which reason it has. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query.

Comment: thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I will try this as soon as possible