# How to get primary key name on laravel query builder

Tags: database, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

Is there a way to get a table's primary key name using the Laravel query builder? Can i do something like

```
$key = DB::table($someTable)->getPrimaryKey();
```

I've looked through the documentation and API but couldn't find any reference to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can get an array of indexes for a table directly using the Schema manager:

```
$indexes = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes($table);
```

OR

```
$indexes = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes($table);
```

And then you can get an array of the columns associated with that index key:

```
$columns = $indexes[ 'primary' ]->getColumns();
```

This function can be used to find the primary key(s) or unique key(s) for a table you know nothing about:

```
public function getTablePrimaryOrUniqueKey($table, $key='') {
    //get the array of table indexes
    $indexes = DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableIndexes($table);

    //abort if there are no indexes
    if(!is_array($indexes)) return false;

    //set up the default array of index keys
    $keys = ['primary', 'unique'];

    //if a key was passed and it is valid, use it...but cast as an array
    if($key!='' && in_array($key, $keys)) $keys = (array) $key;

    //loop through the keys array
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        //keep it honest
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $indexes ) ) {
            //get the columns for this key
            $columns = $indexes[ $key ]->getColumns();

            //if we have an array of columns, we have what we need
            if ( is_array( $columns ) ) {
                return $columns;
            }
        }
    }

    //if you got here, you did not get find what you were looking for
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

my approach is :

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW KEYS FROM {$table} WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'"));
$primaryKey = $result[0]->Column_name;
```

and i use mysql

Comment: This was the right approach for me. Worked like a dream!

Answer (score 3):

The [`Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) class has a [`getKeyName`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1203) function which is `public`.

Inside your model class, you can access the primary key using `$this->getKeyName()`.

Comment: I'm not using an Eloquent model. I want to do it through the query builder.

Comment: In this case I think you'll need to use some SQL. Laravel seems not to have this out of the box.

Comment: The question was based on the query builder, note any database model!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->getKey()` on a model:

`$someModel->getKey();`

Or if you're just trying to get the name of the column, without having an instance of the model:

`app(App\Model::class)->getKeyName()`

Comment: getKey actually returns the value of  the primary key

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of the column? Use `->getKeyName()`

Comment: I'm not using an Eloquent model. I want to do it through the query builder.

Comment: That's not possible. You could make a [SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query) to get it maybe.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wanted the key itself, and this question is one of the top results on Google. 

Answer (score 0):

```
$primary_key = app($builder->getModel())->getKeyName();
```

if you referenced the model when you initialized that Query Builder instance you can retrieve the model reference then use it to get the keyName. but if your just directly called a new Query Builder there isn't a way to see the primary key without doing a select against the table keys, maybe in a subselect?

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i put in my UP migration.

I based my answer off of AXE's answer. So give him the upvotes.
Basically I took his answer and modified it to use collection tools for simpler syntax.

Basically ran a query SHOW KEYS, get the results, collected them, and used contains to see if the PK exists, and removed the PK that was not supposed to be there.

```
$result = collect(DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW KEYS FROM `example_table` WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")));
if ($result->map->Column_name->contains('user_id')) {
    DB::unprepared("ALTER TABLE `example_table` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)");
}
```