# Finding the primary key table name in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, composite

I have an issue with composite primary keys. Having the name of a table, I need to know which columns are foreign keys and I need to know the names of the tables they relate to. 
Now this would be easy if it weren't for the fact that the related table have a composite primary key.

sample:

```
Table Fruits
[pk] FruitId
[pk] OwnerId
     Name 

Table Desserts
[pk] DessertId
     Name
[fk] FruitId
[fk] OwnerId
```

Given the above, I need to query sql "Give me a list of columns in table Desserts that have a fk relationship and tell me the name of the table and column it relates to.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: @DanBracuk But it says SQL Server in the title

Comment: Although the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table wasn't enough, the answer provided by DekDev in the same question did get me the details of composite keys.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to get details, which returns the table name and its primary key, the foreign key table name, the column name, and a lot of other details:

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'MyTable'
```

See [How can I list all foreign keys referencing a given table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483193/how-can-i-list-all-foreign-keys-referencing-a-given-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sorry no. this didn't return anything for my table

Comment: What database do you have selected in SQL Server Management Studio?  If it is set to the default "master" database, then when you execute the above command it will return nothing.  Make sure you select your database.