# How to get the primary key column from a data row?

Tags: c#, primary-key, datarow

In my code there is a data row. Is there a way to get the primary key from this or no? My code is:

```
var PK = data_row.PrimaryKey;
```

However, this I looked up in the MS docs and there is no PrimaryKey property if a data row, there is a property like that for the data table but I don't have the data table here.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table

Comment: No sadly that is not, thanks though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
var PK = data_row.Table.PrimaryKey;
```

this gets the primary key column from the DataTable that the DataRow comes from.

Comment: Great to hear that

Comment: `DataTable.PrimaryKey` returns a `DataColumn[]` - not a single `DataColumn`, because tables can have composite-keys - just FYI.