# How to get primary key or key constraint details for the columns from Information_Schema.Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get primary key or key constraint details for the columns from Information_Schema.Columns?

I am getting the output from sys.indexes , however on joining the query with Information_Schema , i'm getting duplicate records..

```
SELECT      COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMNNAME,  
            DATA_TYPE AS DATATYPE,
            CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
            IS_NULLABLE
            -- Expected -- Another Column --- Which has  Index Details -- Whether Primary Key or Foreign Key or No Key
FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE       TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'



SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     ColumnName = col.name
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 

WHERE t.name = 'MyTable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
;WITH DetailInfo
AS(
SELECT 
    o.name TableName,
    c.name ColumnName,
    t.Name DataType,
    c.max_length MaxLength,
    c.precision Precision,
    c.scale Scale,
    c.is_nullable IsNull,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'PrimaryKey',
    ISNULL(i.is_unique_constraint, 0) 'UniqueKey',
    ISNULL(i.name, 0) 'IndexName',
    ISNULL(i.type_desc, 0) 'IndexType',
    ISNULL(i.is_disabled, 0) 'IndexDisabled'
FROM  sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
)
SELECT * FROM DetailInfo
WHERE TableName = 'Employee'
```

[image]

/*---------OR---------------------*/

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO
;WITH ContraintDetails 
AS(
--KEY_CONSTRAINT
SELECT schema_name(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.[name] TableName,   
        c.name as ColumnName,
        k.type_desc ConstantType,
        k.[name] ConstantName,
        'Is Enforced :' + CASE WHEN  k.is_enforced = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END Details 
FROM sys.key_constraints  k
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns a ON k.parent_object_id = a.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON a.object_id = c.object_id AND a.column_id = c.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON  c.object_id = o.object_id

UNION ALL
--DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
SELECT schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] TableName,   
        c.name as ColumnName,
        con.type_desc ConstantType,
        con.[name] ConstantName,
        col.[name] + ' : ' + con.[definition] Details
FROM sys.default_constraints con
INNER JOIN sys.objects t on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns col on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON col.object_id = c.object_id AND col.column_id = c.column_id

UNION ALL

-- FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
SELECT schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as TableName,
c.name as ColumnName,
fk.type_desc ConstraintType,
fk.name as ConstraintName,
schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name Details
from sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables fk_tab on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables pk_tab on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON fk_cols.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND fk_cols.parent_column_id = c.column_id

UNION ALL

--CHECK_CONSTRAINT
SELECT schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] TableName,
c.name as ColumnName,
con.type_desc  ConstraintType,
con.[name] as constraint_name,
con.[definition] Details
FROM sys.check_constraints con
INNER JOIN sys.objects t on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.all_columns col on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON col.object_id = c.object_id AND col.column_id = c.column_id

UNION ALL
-- INDEX
SELECT schema_name(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.[name] TableName,
    c.name as ColumnName,
    i.type_desc ConstantType,
    i.[name] ConstantName,
    'Is Disabled :' + CASE WHEN  i.is_disabled = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END Details
FROM sys.indexes  i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  i.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON  c.object_id = o.object_id
)
SELECT * FROM ContraintDetails
WHERE TableName = 'HumanResources.Employee' AND  ColumnName = 'BirthDate'

ORDER BY TableName,ColumnName
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you... that was detail. But that doesn't suffice my requirement. Let's say, we have 10 Columns in the table HumanResources.Employee, We need all of the 10 columns and it's details. Column details such as Column Name, Data Type, Data Size, Nullable or Not and Key/ Index details.  Unfortunately Information_Schema.Columns does not give Key / Index details .. and so looking for a join query option

Comment: OK, I will try .

Comment: Updated as per your last comment.

Comment: thank you.. i am using your computation query cte .. that works for me.. thank you so much ..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I think you can get where you want to be using the following queries. The first outputs all constraints and the columns in them. The second outputs all columns and, if they are part of constraints, additional information. In particular, I think that [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/table-constraints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the column you want.

```
-- Constraint columns.
select KCU.TABLE_CATALOG, KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA, KCU.TABLE_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, KCU.COLUMN_NAME, KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as TC inner join
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE as CCU on
      CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME inner join
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as KCU on
      KCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME and KCU.COLUMN_NAME = CCU.COLUMN_NAME
  order by KCU.TABLE_CATALOG, KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA, KCU.TABLE_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION, KCU.COLUMN_NAME;

-- All columns.
select C.TABLE_CATALOG, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME, S.CONSTRAINT_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME, S.ORDINAL_POSITION, S.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as C left outer join
    ( select KCU.TABLE_CATALOG, KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA, KCU.TABLE_NAME, TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME, KCU.COLUMN_NAME, KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION, TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as TC inner join
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE as CCU on
            CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME inner join
          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE as KCU on
            KCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME and KCU.COLUMN_NAME = CCU.COLUMN_NAME
       ) as S on
         S.TABLE_CATALOG = C.TABLE_CATALOG and S.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA and S.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME and S.COLUMN_NAME = C.COLUMN_NAME
  order by C.TABLE_CATALOG, C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME, S.CONSTRAINT_NAME, S.ORDINAL_POSITION, C.COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: thank you and sorry for not having the question much detail. In the Information_Schema.Columns, I am able to retrieve 4 columns : COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE.  Along with these columns, I am trying to get contraint details for the corresponding columns.. not all the columns have keys or constraints..